# Odoo - Convert string to float in python

Tags: python, odoo-9

```
time  = datetime.strptime(str(shift_change_ob.shift_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H:%M")
self.orginal_shift_time = float(time)
```

type(time) is **string** while type(self.orginal_shift_time) is **float**. So I am getting **ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 07:00**. How can I assign string value to float field?

Comment: 07:00 should be converted to what float?

Comment: "print time" prints 07:00. But type(time) is string. I want to assign it to a field whose type is float.

Comment: 07:00 is not assignable to float. Floats are of the form "int.int"

Comment: you want 07:30 in float like 7.5 right? which means 7 an half hour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine you were using colon `strftime("%H:%M")` to seperate hours and minutes, it is not possible to convert to float.

So replace colon with dot `strftime("%H.%M")`, now it will works.

```
>>> time = strftime("%H.%M")
>>> shift_time = float(time)
>>> shift_time
10.55
```

Comment: oh! Thnku :) That was a silly mistake that I had done!

Comment: Thank you soo munch

Answer (score 0):

The time variable will have string,
If you want hour and minute.. use datetime.hour and datetime.minute.
I am assuming shift_change_ob.shift_date is a datetime object. you can get the value from this object itself.

```
shift_change_ob.shift_date.hour
shift_change_ob.shift_date.minute
```

should give what you want.

If you need to store the value as a single float variable you can,

```
time  = datetime.strptime(str(shift_change_ob.shift_date) ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H:%M")
f_time = float(time.split(':')[0] + '.' + str(float(time.strip(':')[1])*(10/6)))
```

10/6 is the factor to convert minutes into decimal.

Comment: Thank You! :) Didnt know about the **10/6** factor